# Planning and licensing: Skype for business outlook integration

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, skype, lync

Folks,
  Ever since Lync became 'skype for business' and the addition of the new Outlook 365 subscriptions, I've found it very difficult to get simple answers to my initial planning questions. First of all, we are running:

- MS Office professional plus 2013 volume licensing
- An in-house exchange server 2013

I want to know does this qualify me (our employees) to using Skype for business with integration with our exchange server? Or am I going to require some additional licensing above and beyond what we already have?

If we do not require any additional licensing, does anyone have a pointer to a setup guide for this scenario? I'm assuming I'd need an additional server for skype for business as opposed to the online version.

FYI, we simply want basic user-to-user
Audio calling
video conferencing
chat
meetings/scheduling through outlook

It does not require any VoIP tie in with our phone system or any ability to dial the outside world.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to do that on premises then:

**Question part1 (Which licenses):**

I do not know any details for your Microsoft contract, but in general based on your "no PSTN calls needed info":

- Each SfB Front End server requires a SfB Server license (1 or 3 or more depending on your setup).
- Each SfB user (or device) requires a SfB standard CAL which allows them do do peer2peer chats and calls.
- Each user which should do conferencing & desktop sharing need an ADDITIONAL Enterprise CAL (Standard CAL + Enterprise CAL!)
- Client licenses are required for using the Skype for Business client. (These are included in Office 2016 Professional Plus)

You also should check the Licensing Guide from Microsoft [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/2/9/229F0436-97D4-454F-8ED9-7138719335F0/Lync%20Licensing%20Guide%20November%202013%20Customer%20and%20Partner.docx) or [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/C/7/8C7C30DA-0386-4698-8BBB-367EAC8C4352/Lync%20Licensing%20Guide%20February%202013.pdf).

**Question part2 (How to set that up):**

The installation highly depends on your existing environment. To give you an short overview how it *might* look like:

- You need an MS SQL server (standard or Enterprise as seen [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951388.aspx))
- You need 3 SfB Frontend Server
- You need 2 SfB Edge Server
- You need a Reverse Proxy (for example the MS Web application proxy; see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/224-use-ms-web-application-proxy-as-reverse-proxy-and-adfs-with-skype-for-business.html))
- You might need an Office Online Server (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/248-step-by-step-configuring-office-online-server-with-skype-for-business.html)) if you wish to allow users to upload an PowerPoint presentation for the meeting

Comment: BastianW - I've marked your response as the answer. The main thing you answered for me which I assumed, but needed confirmation on was that the Office professional plus volume licensing doesn't provide me any licensing for the server components. I wasn't sure if my nature of granting one SfB Client licensing it would allow someone to download and install the server.

Comment: Its better explained in the [Skype_for_Business_Server_2015_Factsheet.pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/9/0/E9064F52-0264-465E-B638-BF205B16E622/Skype_for_Business_Server_2015_Factsheet.pdf) where it outlined that you need two type of licenses. Unfortunately this document exists only in German language so I posted the info's from the above website.